# Sudo yum update errors

Tags: centos6, yum

I recently tried installing HHVM on my Centos VPS today without luck. I then tried to update my VPS and received the following errors below. I'm quite new to the command line so I don't have a clue as to what I did (unfortunately). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                            | 9.4 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * epel: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                          | 4.4 MB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.4 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 6.3 MB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.3 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                        |  19 kB     00:00     
hhvm                                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00     
hhvm/primary_db                                          |  66 kB     00:00     
mariadb                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
mariadb/primary_db                                       |  18 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                       | 5.3 MB     00:00     
vz-base                                                  |  951 B     00:00     
vz-base/primary                                          | 1.3 kB     00:00     
vz-base                                                                     3/3
vz-updates                                               |  951 B     00:00     
vz-updates/primary                                       | 2.2 kB     00:00     
vz-updates                                                                  8/8
webtatic                                                 | 3.6 kB     00:00     
webtatic/primary_db                                      | 216 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rpm.x86_64 0:4.8.0-37.el6 will be updated
---> Package rpm.x86_64 0:4.9.1.3-6.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.2.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.8.0-37.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: librpm.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpm.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmio.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmio.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.9.1.3-6.el6 will be an update
---> Package rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.8.0-37.el6 will be updated
---> Package rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.9.1.3-6.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: librpmbuild.so.2()(64bit) for package: rpm-python-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmsign.so.0()(64bit) for package: rpm-python-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libdb.x86_64 0:5.2.36-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rpm-build-libs.x86_64 0:4.9.1.3-6.el6 will be installed
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.8.0-37.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: librpm.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpm.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmio.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librpmio.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: librpm.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: rpm-libs-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               librpm.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated By: rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64 (hhvm)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: librpmio.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: rpm-libs-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               librpmio.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated By: rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64 (hhvm)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: librpmio.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: rpm-libs-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               librpmio.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated By: rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64 (hhvm)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.5-49.el6_5.3.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: librpm.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: rpm-libs-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               librpm.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated By: rpm-libs-4.9.1.3-6.el6.x86_64 (hhvm)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing hhvm.repo from etc/yum.repos.d solved it.